# OpenVPN - ping and dns ok, everything else no connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, vpn, openvpn

I'm trying to connect to my company network via OpenVPN. OpenVPN client connects. Log says no problems.

Nslookup and ping to local, remote and internet hosts as also ips works in cmd.exe

Nevertheless all applications and browser and explorer.exe dont work. They dont get a connection. Neither local, remote nor internet.

I'm using windows 10 and don't use any third party firewall, etc.

Why is everything working in CMD but nowhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem myself. There was a problem with the MTU. Since the standard MTU is 1500, but my internet provider takes some bytes for overhead (Telekom Magenta Hybrid), I had to lower the MTU in the OpenVPN config to 1384.

Therefore I used the following command in the .ovpn-file:

```
link-mtu 1384
```

This fixed all my problems.